# MySQL Full Text Search with utf8 (Persian/Arabic)

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have problem with full text search just on UTF8/Unicode Persian/Arabic Language (nothing found from querys).

- Tables are set with utf8/utf8_persian_ci on encoding.
- Using `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");` for Unicode Querys.
- English strings work fine.

***Below is My search codes:***

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("search");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'"); 

$q = $_GET['q'];

?>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="q" value="<?php echo $q; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Search!">
</form>
<hr>
<?php
if (isset($q)) 
{
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT *, MATCH(name, description) AGAINST ('$q') AS score from search_test WHERE MATCH (name, description) AGAINST('$q') order by score desc");
    $ant = mysql_num_rows($res);
    if ($ant > 0) 
    { // query provided results – display results
        echo ("<br/><h2>Search results for \"$q\":</h2>");
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($res)) 
        {
            echo ("<h3>{$result['name']} ({$result['score']})</h3>{$result['description']}<br/><br/>");
        }
    }
    else 
    { // query provided 0 results – display 0 hit message
        echo ("<br/><h2>Nothing Found \"$q\" query</h2>");
    }
}
?>
```

***where is the problem or how can I search with full-text on Unicode language ?***

Comment: and you have FULLTEXT index on `name` and `description` ? Also I hope you know you have a big hole in your script and it's vulnerable to SQL injections, right?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @MihaiIorga Yes , I use it . `name` and `description` are indexed and work successfully with English strings , but with Persian/Arabic strings don't find anything from query .

Comment: try to print your query before execution to see what is actually sent ..

Comment: @MihaiIorga Sorry , but how can I print my query before execution ?

Comment: `$res = "SELECT *, MATCH(name, description) AGAINST ('$q') AS score from search_test WHERE MATCH (name, description) AGAINST('$q') order by score desc";` `echo $res; die;`, remove `mysql_query`

Comment: @MihaiIorga Printout is :`SELECT *, MATCH(name, description) AGAINST ('آزمایشی') AS score from search_test WHERE MATCH (name, description) AGAINST('آزمایشی') order by score desc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexed columns must <= 1000 byte encoding.

You cannot do a FULLTEXT search on Persian letters as the have > 1000 byte encoding. As it is stated [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-restrictions.html).

for example your `آزمایشی` has the following character encoding bytes map:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1570
    [1] => 1586
    [2] => 1605
    [3] => 1575
    [4] => 1740
    [5] => 1588
    [6] => 1740
)
```

Comment: Thanks , I try to using full-text search for create a search engine for my website , have a better way for do that on Persian language ?

Comment: Nope, I'm not that familiar with Arabic languages. Good luck.

Comment: It just came into my mind, but it is not a such good solution as it involves duplicate `name` and `description`, here goes: What if you duplicate the data `name_unicode` and transform what is in `name` in unicode and then when you search you transform the search data in unicode also and you can make FULLTEXT search on same data type with <1000 byte encoding?

Answer (score 4):

MySQL fulltext search works well for Persian. Just make sure of the following where needed:

1. `COLLATION = utf8_persian_ci` & `CHARACTER SET = utf8`. (Databases, Tables, and Columns).
2. Index words of 3 letters and more. This is Very Important for Arabic, `ft_min_word_len = 3` (see `show variables like "ft_%";`)
3. Check the version of MySQL (5.5 or 5.6), and Engine (InnoDb or MyISAM)